# Is it possible to specify content database name while creating the Excel Service Application using powershell script?

Tags: 2013, powershell, excel-services, content-database

I want to create the Excel Service Application as it is required to use the Excel Web Access Web Part. Firs I tried to create the application using sharepoint but GUI not providing facility to specify the content database name so I thought to make it using powershell script. I searched over internet a lot but found the power shell scripts which are just creating the service application not providing the content database name..

What should I do to specify? Or is it not possible?

Please provide some guidelines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Excel Service Application has no Database itself.

But in order for it to have access to the Content Database of your web application you have to execute the following powershell (for each WebApp where you want to allow Excel Services to access spreadsheets from)

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication -identity http://<WebApplication>
$w.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("<Domain>\<Username>")
```

To see which Service applications has databases (and which can be shared) see [Services in SharePoint Server 2013](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=259425)

For more information about configuring Excel service see [Configure Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219698.aspx)